# How can I extract my automatically transferred luggage at a connection?

Tags: air-travel, transit, south-america, short-connections

My luggage is set to automatically transfer from:

-Rio - Sao Paulo (LAN)
-Sao Paulo - Bogota (LAN)
-Bogota - Caracas (COPA)

I'd like to get it out at Bogota, as I have left some non-vital mediciation in the bag.

Is it possible to get it and how do I get it?

Comment: When checking in, just ask them to only tag the bags as far as Bogota?

Comment: To get your bag you will need to clear immgration if you want at one of the stops in another country.  Then check it back in.  Might it be easier to carry yiur meds in your carry on?

Comment: I tried that but because it's a separate airline he said he couldn't do it